# Showing convergence for certain values of P

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine for which values of p the following series converges:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{(\ln n)^P}{n}$$

So far, just from looking at various values for $P$, it seems to be that any $P$ should work, but I'm not certain enough. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Apply the alternating series test. (Show that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \dfrac{(\log k)^p}{k}  = 0$ irrespective of $p$.)

Comment: I've done this (and it's actually fairly neat with repeated use of L'Hopital's rule), but now I just want a good way to show that it's always decreasing past some certain point. Does this involve solving $n > (\ln n)^P$? Or this is a good time to use the definition of the limit?

Comment: I think I have a solid answer now, should I share it here?

Comment: @snario, You have to show that $$ \frac{(\ln n)^P}{n} \ge \frac{(\ln (n+1))^P}{n+1} $$. You can also show that $\frac{\log (n)}{\log (n+1)}^p$ is bounded from above by $1$, by which the result follows.

Comment: If you have an answer, you are [welcome to share it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: As to ultimately decreasing, replace $k$ by $x$ and differentiate, using the Quotient Rule. The denominator is positive. The numerator is $(\log x)^{p-1}((p-1)-\log x)$, in the long run negative.